# iOS layout manually changed becomes empty in UI

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, autolayout, constraints

My target is to control the custom views layout manually during portrait or landscape mode. At initiation, the View can normally display sub view1 and view2 by portrait or landscape mode, that means my constraints setting should be fine. But after rotate, the view will display empty, not my expected view1 and view2 layout. I cannot understand how to force UI refresh to display my new layout.

The below is my code snippet, and test result.

---

```
class ConstraintViewController: UIViewController 
{
    let metrics = ["topMargin":64,"leftMargin":10,"rightMargin":10,"bottomMargin":10,"interSpace":20]
    var viewsDictionary: Dictionary<String,UIView!>?
    var view1: UIView?
    var view2: UIView?
    let button1 = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    let label1 = UILabel() as UILabel
    let atRest = "Doesn't do much"
    let atWork = "Secret Agent"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Remove conflicting NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraints.
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints(self.view.constraints())

        setupElements()
        println("In viewDidLoad")
     if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation)) {
            //Landscape code
            isPortrait = false
            landscapeConstraint()  
        } else {
            //Portrait code
            isPortrait = true
            portraitConstraint()
        }  
    }

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation)) {
            //Landscape code
            println("Detect landscape mode")
                NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints(self.view.constraints())
                self.view1!.removeConstraints(self.view1!.constraints())
                self.view2!.removeConstraints(self.view2!.constraints())
                self.view!.removeConstraints(self.view!.constraints())

                //self.view.removeConstraints(<#constraints: [AnyObject]#>)
                landscapeConstraint()

                self.view1?.layoutIfNeeded()
                self.view2?.layoutIfNeeded()
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        } else {
            //Portrait code
            println("Detect portrait mode")
           NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints(self.view.constraints())
                self.view1!.removeConstraints(self.view1!.constraints())
                self.view2!.removeConstraints(self.view2!.constraints())
                self.view!.removeConstraints(self.view!.constraints())
                portraitConstraint()

                self.view1?.layoutIfNeeded()
                self.view2?.layoutIfNeeded()
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    func setupElements() {

        //Make a view
        view1 = UIView()
        view1!.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        view1!.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        //Make a second view
        view2 = UIView()
        view2!.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        view2!.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.75, green: 0.75, blue: 0.1, alpha: 1.0)

        //Make a label
        label1.text = atRest
        label1.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

        //Make a button
        button1.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        button1.setTitle("Platypus", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button1.addTarget(self, action: "buttonPressed", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        button1.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        button1.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        //Add the views
        view.addSubview(view1!)
        view.addSubview(view2!)
        view2!.addSubview(button1)
        view2!.addSubview(label1)

        viewsDictionary = ["view":self.view,"view1":view1,"view2":view2,"button1":button1,"label1":label1]

    }

    func landscapeConstraint() {
        //--------------- landscape constraints
        println("In landscapeConstraint")
        //make dictionary for views
        //views
        let view1_constraint_V:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-topMargin-[view1]-bottomMargin-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: metrics, views: viewsDictionary!)
        let view2_constraint_V:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-topMargin-[view2]-bottomMargin-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: metrics, views: viewsDictionary!)
        let view_constraint_H:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-10-[view1]-20-[view2]-10-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllTop, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary!)
        let view1_width_constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view1!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view2!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

        self.view.addConstraints(view1_constraint_V)
        self.view.addConstraints(view2_constraint_V)
        self.view.addConstraints(view_constraint_H)
        self.view.addConstraint(view1_width_constraint)

        //controls
        let control_constraint_H:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[button1(>=20)]-interSpace-[label1(>=30)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterY, metrics: metrics, views: viewsDictionary!)
        let control_constraint_V:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[button1(20)]-10-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary!)

        view2!.addConstraints(control_constraint_H)
        view2!.addConstraints(control_constraint_V)

    }

    func portraitConstraint() {
        //--------------- portrait constraints
        println("In portraitConstraint")
        //make dictionary for views
        //views
        let view1_constraint_H:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-leftMargin-[view1]-rightMargin-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: metrics, views: viewsDictionary!)
        let view2_constraint_H:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-leftMargin-[view2]-rightMargin-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: metrics, views: viewsDictionary!)
        let view_constraint_V:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-topMargin-[view1]-interSpace-[view2]-bottomMargin-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllLeading, metrics: metrics, views: viewsDictionary!)
        let view1_height_constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view1!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view2!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

        self.view.addConstraints(view1_constraint_H)
        self.view.addConstraints(view2_constraint_H)
        self.view.addConstraints(view_constraint_V)
        self.view.addConstraint(view1_height_constraint)

        //controls
        let control_constraint_H:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[button1(>=80)]-interSpace-[label1(>=100)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterY, metrics: metrics, views: viewsDictionary!)
        let control_constraint_V:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[button1(40)]-40-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary!)

        view2!.addConstraints(control_constraint_H)
        view2!.addConstraints(control_constraint_V)
    }
}
```

Test result:

The init layout view display correct.

After rotation, the view display is empty, not updated to the expected layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where in `viewWillTransitionToSize` you write

```
 self.view!.removeConstraints(self.view!.constraints())
```

this removes both the new constraints you have added, and *also* the initial default constraints created when the view was created. Without those default constraints, the size of the view shrinks to zero, and the size of your subviews shrink to match.

You can create a new instance variable

```
var viewInitialConstraints: [AnyObject]?
```

and then in `viewDidAppear` (it doesn't work in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`)

```
viewInitialConstraints = view.constraints()
```

(move your initial addition of extra constraints to `ViewDidAppear`) and then you can write in `viewWillTransitionToSize`

```
view.removeConstraints(view.constraints())
view.addConstraints(viewInitialConstraints)
```

or, you might try keeping track of the constraints you add:

```
view.removeConstraints(viewExtraConstraints)
```

Comment: much appreciate. It works after saving the container view init constraints.